# Table splitting - is it possible to split a table into two entirely independent entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple user table:

```
CREATE TABLE User
 (
UserId int,
UserName nvarchar(35),
Password nvarchar(size),
 );
```

I want to split this up into two entities in EF6. User and UserPassword. These represent two very different business needs, but happen to live on the same table.

So I create two entities.

```
public class User
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class UserPassword
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Password{ get; set; }
}
```

I have maps like so

```
class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
    }
}

class PasswordMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserPassword>
{
    public PasswordMap()
    {
        ToTable("User");
        Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
    }
}
```

But when I use these entities I get the following error:

Message = "The entity types 'UserPassword' and 'User' cannot share table 'User' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them."

I do not want to create a relationship. I am having trouble setting up table per hierarchy. I don't want a discriminator. I really just want to have two separate ways to get to the same table that are discreet. Is there a way to do this other than creating two contexts?

Comment: "I do not want to create a relationship." But you already did when they were made to live in the same table. What happens when you insert a new user?

Comment: The password is nullable. Adding a new user does not effect the password.

Comment: I think I'd just workaround the problem by having an updatable view in the database for `UserPassword` and then using that as the table.

Comment: Awesome. Exactly the kind of solution I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. As per my comment, if you created an updatable view for `UserPassword` then you could use that as the table for the entity. EF will neither know nor care that updating that is actually updating the users table, and vice versa.